# override internalFrameClosing method

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

What I am trying to do is make it so when somone clicks the x button on my jinternalframe that it does not get rid of it, simply hides it.  Here is my code but it still gets rid of the frame.

```
characterFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter(){
    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        characterFrame.setVisible(false);
        return;
    }
});
```

Any ideas??  I want to override what happens when you close the window and only have it run my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does get rid of it"? And who is "it"?

Comment: Try to remove the closing listener before add yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the [`JInternalFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) method with the `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` what you are looking for ? It is not entirely clear from your question

Comment: yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes :D  thanks... sorry that was dumb of me.